# share to whatsapp automatically without menu ios

Tags: ios, audio, share, whatsapp

I have a sound which i want to share on Whatsapp, using the UIDocumentInteractionController it is working perfectly, but i don't want to promote the user to choose Whatsapp, i want it to be picked immediately. Is that possible ?

For the text share it works as i want, it immediately open Whatsapp using the deep linking

```
whatsapp://send?text=test
```

I dont want this menu to be shown when sharing sound:
[image: menu]

Answer (score 1):

For Text :

```
NSString * msg = @"Your Text";
NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",msg];

NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];

}

else{

UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

For Image :

.h file :

```
<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>

@property (retain) UIDocumentInteractionController * documentInteractionController;
```

.m file :

```
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]]){

        UIImage     * iconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR IMAGE"];
        NSString    * savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];

        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iconImage, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

        _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
        _documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
        _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;

        [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];


    } else  {

        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
 }
```

Comment: I already did this, i dont want to show them the menu when you call presentOpenInMenuFromRect, i want the Whatsapp to be immediately picked.

Comment: I've been trying to do this too. Did you have any luck?